# Get all similar documents with doc2vec

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am actually working with `doc2vec` from gensim library and I want to get all similarities with probabilites not only the top 10 similarities provided by `model.docvecs.most_similar()`

Once my model is trained

```
In [1]: print(model)
Out [1]: Doc2vec(...)
```

If I use `model.docvecs.most_similar()` I get only the Top 10 similar docs

```
In [2]: model.docvecs.most_similar('1')
Out [2]: [('2007', 0.9171321988105774),
 ('606', 0.5638039708137512),
 ('2578', 0.530228853225708),
 ('4506', 0.5193327069282532),
 ('2550', 0.5178008675575256),
 ('4620', 0.5098666548728943),
 ('1296', 0.5071642994880676),
 ('3943', 0.5070815086364746),
 ('438', 0.5057751536369324),
 ('1922', 0.5048809051513672)]
```

And I am looking to get all probilities not only the top 10 for some analysis.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`most_similar()` takes an optional `topn` parameter, with a default value of `10`, meaning just the top 10 results will be returned.

If you supply another integer, such as the total number of doc-vectors known to the model, then that many sorted results will be provided.

(You can also supply Python `None`, which returns all similarities *unsorted*, in the same order as the vectors are stored in the model.)

Note these values are *cosine similarities*, with a range of values from -1.0 to 1.0, *not* 'probabilities'.